# I am trying to create a visiting card in canvas when user inputs ID

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

1. I am trying to create a visiting card based on ID input which will iterate over my object and fetch the related data on button click. I want to show the fields in an object on canvas element. Initially I was thinking to show it on canvas which creates a default space for that I added code to fillText I am having hard time to arrange it on browser.I think I need to add CSS and play with height and width. Can someone guide me what is the best approach.
2. Moreover, while reading a blog on [Canvas-Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-canvas-tutorial-introduction/) I came to know we can add multiple shapes using Canvas API such as rectangle. Since instead of showing the card details on canvas I was trying to add a rectangle shape, make it transparent and add data in that rectangle so it will be more interactive. I need some guidance in doing that.

[JSBin - Demo](https://jsbin.com/lukesamuga/edit?html,js,output)

```js
var details = {
  "Employees": [{
    "ID": "Winterfall",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Snow",
    "email": "johnsnow@winterfall.com",
    "call": 121212,
    "Work": [{
      "company": "Google",
      "Designation": "Principle Architect"
    }]
  }, {
    "ID": "Castly Rock",
    "FirstName": "Tyrion",
    "LastName": "Lannister",
    "email": "tyrionLan@Castly.com",
    "call": 111111,
    "Work": [{
      "company": "Amazon",
      "Designation": "Vice President"
    }]
  }, {
    "ID": "High Garden",
    "FirstName": "Samuel",
    "LastName": "Tally",
    "email": "Samueltally@highgarden.com",
    "call": 777777,
    "Work": [{
      "Company": "Yahoo",
      "Designation": "Consultant"
    }]
  }]
};


function getEmployeeData() {
  var self = details,
    arr = [],
    value = document.getElementById("inputElement").value,
    isEmpId = self.Employees,
    len = isEmpId.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (value === isEmpId[i].ID) {
      var name = isEmpId[i].FirstName + " " + isEmpId[i].LastName
      call = isEmpId[i].call, email = isEmpId[i].email, company = isEmpId[i].Work[0].company,
        title = isEmpId[i].Work[0].Designation;
      drawCard(name, title, company, email, call);
      return true;
    }
  }

};

function drawCard(m, n, o, p, q) {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("rectangleCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //context.textAlign = "center"
  context.fillText(m, 100, 100);
  context.fillText(n, 200, 50);
  context.fillText(o, 300, 60);
  context.fillText(p, 400, 70);
  context.fillText(q, 500, 80);
  //drawText(320, 080, "DEEPAK DWIJ", "rgb(80,80,80)");

  // var x = 20, y = 80, width=100, height=80; 

  // var shape = new Path2D();
  // shape.rect(x+100,y-50,width-40,height);

  // context.fillStyle = "#00695c";
  // context.fill(shape);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Business card</h4>
<input type="text" id="inputElement" placeholder="Enter employee id">
<button id="button" onclick="getEmployeeData()">Click to get Data</button>
<br>
<hr>
<div>
  <canvas id="rectangleCanvas" height="300" width="500" style="border: solid 1px black;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTML5 Canvas is just a raster image. You don't add shapes and text to the canvas, you can't manipulate them through CSS; you just draw them on the canvas at the coordinates specified.

This has the consequence that, anytime you need to change, for example, the text displayed in the canvas, you have to redraw the whole thing. Your drawCard function should do this.

Also, IMHO, any shape on the canvas that's not dynamic should not be drawn using code; rather, it should be on a static image that you draw over the canvas before drawing text and other dynamic shapes.

```
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.src = "URL_of_your_image.png";

function drawCard(m, n, o, p, q){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("rectangleCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);

  // Draw the text etc.
}
```

You should design the layout of the card in advance, before writing any code; for example, in a sheet of graph paper, you decide where everything goes, take note of the position and dimensions of each rectangle where you're going to put each text element. Design first, implement later; trying to do both at the same time will make you waste a lot of time.

In order to layout your text correctly, you may need to use the [context.measureText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) method before actually drawing the text in the canvas. This is a must for:

- Multiline text
- Editable text that may not fit inside the width of your box
- Complex text layout, for scripts such as Arabic and Devanagari.

For a consistent look, you shouldn't rely on default fonts installed in the user's computer; rather, you should consider using web fonts. You should use [Web Font Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) in order to ensure that the font is loaded before you draw your text.